# Error drawing text on NSImage in PyObjC

Tags: cocoa, image, annotations, pyobjc, ruby-cocoa

I'm trying to overlay an image with some text using PyObjC, while striving to answer my question, ["Annotate images using tools built into OS X"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229171/annotate-images-using-tools-built-into-os-x).  By referencing [CocoaMagic](http://www.rubycocoa.com/cocoa-magic-for-gruff-graphs/2/), a RubyObjC replacement for [RMagick](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/), I've come up with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from AppKit import *

source_image = "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Nature/Aurora.jpg"
final_image = "/Library/Desktop Pictures/.loginwindow.jpg"
font_name = "Arial"
font_size = 76
message = "My Message Here"

app = NSApplication.sharedApplication()  # remove some warnings

# read in an image
image = NSImage.alloc().initWithContentsOfFile_(source_image)
image.lockFocus()

# prepare some text attributes
text_attributes = NSMutableDictionary.alloc().init()
font = NSFont.fontWithName_size_(font_name, font_size)
text_attributes.setObject_forKey_(font, NSFontAttributeName)
text_attributes.setObject_forKey_(NSColor.blackColor, NSForegroundColorAttributeName)

# output our message
message_string = NSString.stringWithString_(message)
size = message_string.sizeWithAttributes_(text_attributes)
point = NSMakePoint(400, 400)
message_string.drawAtPoint_withAttributes_(point, text_attributes)

# write the file
image.unlockFocus()
bits = NSBitmapImageRep.alloc().initWithData_(image.TIFFRepresentation)
data = bits.representationUsingType_properties_(NSJPGFileType, nil)
data.writeToFile_atomically_(final_image, false)
```

When I run it, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/clinton/Work/Problems/TellAtAGlance/ObviouslyTouched.py", line 24, in <module>
    message_string.drawAtPoint_withAttributes_(point, text_attributes)
ValueError: NSInvalidArgumentException - Class OC_PythonObject: no such selector: set
```

Looking in the docs for drawAtPoint:withAttributes:, it says, "You should only invoke this method when an NSView has focus."  NSImage is not a subclass of NSView, but I would hope this would work, and something very similar seems to work in the Ruby example.

What do I need to change to make this work?

---

I rewrote the code, converting it faithfully, line for line, into an Objective-C Foundation tool.  It works, without problems.  [I would be happy to post if here if there is a reason to do so.]

The question then becomes, how does:

```
[message_string drawAtPoint:point withAttributes:text_attributes];
```

differ from

```
message_string.drawAtPoint_withAttributes_(point, text_attributes)
```

?  Is there a way to tell which "OC_PythonObject" is raising the NSInvalidArgumentException?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the problems in the above code:

```
text_attributes.setObject_forKey_(NSColor.blackColor, NSForegroundColorAttributeName)
->
text_attributes.setObject_forKey_(NSColor.blackColor(), NSForegroundColorAttributeName)

bits = NSBitmapImageRep.alloc().initWithData_(image.TIFFRepresentation)
data = bits.representationUsingType_properties_(NSJPGFileType, nil)
->
bits = NSBitmapImageRep.imageRepWithData_(image.TIFFRepresentation())
data = bits.representationUsingType_properties_(NSJPEGFileType, None)
```

Minor typos indeed.

Note that the middle portion of the code can be replaced with this more-readable variant:

```
# prepare some text attributes
text_attributes = { 
    NSFontAttributeName : NSFont.fontWithName_size_(font_name, font_size),
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : NSColor.blackColor() 
}

# output our message 
NSString.drawAtPoint_withAttributes_(message, (400, 400), text_attributes)
```

I learned this by looking at the source code to [NodeBox](http://nodebox.net), the twelve lines of [psyphography.py](http://dev.nodebox.net/browser/nodebox/trunk/play/psyphography.py) and [cocoa.py](http://dev.nodebox.net/browser/nodebox/trunk/src/nodebox/graphics/cocoa.py), particularly the save and _getImageData methods.